# Conflict between zoom and mouseover/mouseout events with d3 on two different layers

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, svg

I am working on a simple bar chart with basic zoom and tooltip display when the mouse enters a bar.
I have a conflict between two events that get triggered on different layers of my d3 code. I have a svg:rect whose purpose is to catch the d3 zoom events, and I have a sibling node, a svg called layer1 that contains the bars of my bar chart. Each of these bars are simple svg:rect, that are children nodes of my layer1 svg. I am attaching mouseover and mouseout events on each of my bars to display a tooltip (I'm using https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/).

My problem is the following:

If I try to zoom with the mouse wheel when the mouse is on the plot but outside a bar, it works. However, when the mouse is on a bar, the d3-tip gets displayed but I can't zoom in/out anymore, the mouse wheel will just make the whole page scroll up or down.

I already tried the approach described in the following link with no success:

[Handling Mouse Events in Overlapping SVG Layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799116/handling-mouse-events-in-overlapping-svg-layers)

I also wanted to directly handle the mouseover and mouseout from the evt_catcher layer by appending it to my main svg AFTER appending layer1, but the problem is that the functions tip.show and tip.hide actually compute the position of the tooltip from the event.target/d3.event.target, which here would be associated with the evt_catcher layer and not a bar anymore.

So to make this approach successful, I would need to get the svg node associated with one bar from the coordinates of the mouse, and I have no idea how to do that. Document.elementFromPoint() seemed to be promising but only gives the topmost element, which would be here evt_catcher again...

Here is some relevant code:

```
// appending evt_catcher layer
this.evt_catcher = this.svg.append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'overlay')
   .attr('width', this.width)
   .attr('height', this.height);

// appending layer1 layer (will contain the bars)
this.layer1 = this.svg.append('svg')
   .attr('height', this.height)
   .attr('width', this.width);

// creating the d3-tip
this.tip = d3.tip()
   .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
   .offset([-10, 0])
   .html(function(d) {
      return d[1].toFixed(2);
   });

// attaching the d3-tip to the main svg
this.svg.call(this.tip);

// defining the d3.behavior.zoom function
this.zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
   .x(this.x)
   .scaleExtent([1, 32])
   .on('zoom', function() {
      d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
      d3.event.sourceEvent.preventDefault();
      /* my zoom code */
      });
});

// creating the bars representing the data
var bars = this.layer1.selectAll('.bar').data(data.series.values);
bars.transition()
   .attr('x', function(d) {return that.x(d[0]);})
   .attr('width', that.range_band * that.zoom.scale())
   .attr('y', function(d) { return d[1] < 0 ? that.y(0): that.y(d[1]); })
   .attr('height', function(d) {
      return Math.abs(that.y(d[1]) - that.y(0));
   });

bars.enter().append('rect')
   .attr('class', 'bar')
   .attr('x', function(d) {return that.x(d[0]);})
   .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
   .attr('width', that.range_band * that.zoom.scale())
   .attr('y', function(d) { return d[1] < 0 ? that.y(0): that.y(d[1]); })
   .attr('height', 0)
   .on('mouseover', that.tip.show) // attaching mouseover event to trigger the display of the tooltip
   .on('mouseout', that.tip.hide) //attaching mouseout event to hide the the tooltip
 .transition()
   .attr('height', function(d) {
      return Math.abs(that.y(d[1]) - that.y(0));
   });

bars.exit().transition()
   .attr('height', 0)
   .remove();

// attaching the zoom event to the evt_catcher layer
this.evt_catcher.call(this.zoom);
```

Any idea?